# Pretty print a Kotlin Json Serializable

Tags: json, kotlin

How do you pretty print a Kotlin Serializable class so the keys are formatted on separate lines, and not on one line (the default)? `Json.encodeToString` prints everything on one line. I see the [prettyPrint](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-json/kotlinx.serialization.json/-json-builder/pretty-print-indent.html) documentation in the [kotlinx-serialization-json](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-json/) library but the JsonBuilder and JsonConfiguration have private constructors.

Example serializable:

```
@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
data class MyObject(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int
)

val myObject = MyObject(name = "hello", age = 2)
val string = Json.encodeToString(myObject)
print(string)
```

The above prints `{"name":"hello","age":2}` but I want everything to be on separate lines.

Answer (score 6):

Using this will give access to the [JsonBuilder](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-json/kotlinx.serialization.json/-json-builder/) printing options.

```
val prettyJson = Json { // this returns the JsonBuilder
    prettyPrint = true
    // optional: specify indent
    prettyPrintIndent = " "
}

val myObject = MyObject(name = "hello", age = 2)
val string = prettyJson.encodeToString(myObject)
print(string)
```

This prints:

```
{
 "name": "hello",
 "age": 2
}
```